# How to set a Property of a List?

Tags: c#, list, properties, set

I am not sure, but it seems i can not set a Property of a List?
The code in the (set) section does not get executed, debugger does not stop in the set when placing a break-point.

if a list property is dealt with differently? and if there is a link of some reading on this subject.

```
    class test
    {
        public test()
        {
            id = new List<string>();
            _id = new List<string>();
        }
        private List<string> _id;

        public List<string> id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                _id = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
test t = new test();
t.id.Add("one");
```

Comment: Your post is very garbled at best.  In the future, you will want to spend more time explaining what the problem is and what you have tried

Comment: Sorry, i missed the first part is "test class" , and the last 2 lines is from the main class, the set section in the test class is not getting executed, i am not sure if the code has a problem, or the logic is not correct?

Comment: Are you asking why `test.Id.Add("one");` does not call the setter?

Comment: @ Jonathon Chase Yes, did not call it. tried a breakpoint, did not stop neither.

Comment: There is no property setter that is being called when adding an item to a list. List<T>Add() is a method - why would you expect a property setter (of a  property that is related to your `test` type, but entirely unrelated to the type List<T>) being invoked  when you actually invoke a method of List<T>? It seems to me your question is an XY problem. Instead of asking about your attempt X (= making a property setter being called) to solve a problem Y (= ???), rather ask directly or explain your actual problem Y you tried to solve with X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The code in the (set) section does not get executed, debugger does not stop in the set when placing a break-point.

It appears that your question is, *"why is the `set` accessor not called when I do: `t.id.Add("one");`"*

The reason is simply that the `set` accessor is for the `List` itself. Your code is not setting `t.id` to a new `List<string>`, rather it is calling the `.Add` method of the object returned from the `t.id` property.

So the execution would look something like:

1. The `get` accessor is called when you do `t.id`, and it returns the instance of `_id`
2. The `.Add` method of `_id` is then called, and the string `"one"` is added to the private backing field `_id`

Note that in your existing code, the `set` *does* get called from the constructor, when you explicitly set the `id` to a new List.

---

You've stated that your goal is *"to change some other properties when I add an item to id"*. There are a few ways to do this, but probably the simplest to understand and implement is:

1. In the `get` accessor for the list, return a copy of the list. This prevents clients from adding an item directly through the `Add` method. Also note that there is no need for a `set` accessor.
2. Provide a separate `AddId` method on your class, which is what the clients would have to call to actually add an item. This is where you have the opportunity to do something else when items are added to the list.

For example:

```
class Test
{ 
    private readonly List<string> id = new List<string>();

    // Return a copy of our private list
    public List<string> Id => id?.ToList();

    public void AddId(string newId)
    {
        id.Add(newId);
        // do something else here when we add a new item
    }
}
```

Note that this might cause some confusion for clients of your class, because they can still do `test.Id.Add("invalid item");` and they won't get any error, but it also won't add anything to the private list. If they want to add something to the list, they have to call the `AddId` method:

```
t.AddId("one");
```

Comment: so what is the proper way to do a setter when i add an item to the list?

Comment: i want to change some other properties when i add an item to id.

Comment: Ok, I updated the answer with an example. There are better ways to do this, but I think they may be more complex than you want.

Comment: Thank you, that did it!